# svn:externals bring back

Tags: svn

I have deleted directory coming from svn:external, simply by rm -rf,
now it does not come back when I do svn up in directory above, where
are externals set.

It just says that directory is under some revision and nothing more?

How can I fetch that directory again?

Answer (score 1):

`svn:external` is a property set in the directory containing the external repository folder.

You may want to try `svn revert` on the deepest directory that contained your removed external reference.
Be careful though that you only revert directories you have removed and not accidentally revert modified but uncommitted files.